# Akka HTTP Source Streaming vs regular request handling

Tags: akka-http, http-streaming, http-pipelining

What is the advantage of using  [Source Streaming](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html) vs the regular way of handling requests? My understanding that in both cases

1. The TCP connection will be reused
2. Back-pressure will be applied between the client and the server

The only advantage of  Source Streaming I can see is if there is a very large response and the client prefers to consume it in smaller chunks.

My use case is that I have a very long list of users (millions), and I need to call a service that performs some filtering on the users, and returns a subset.

Currently, on the server side I expose a batch API, and on the client, I just split the users into chunks of 1000, and make X batch calls in parallel using Akka HTTP Host API.

I am considering switching to HTTP streaming, but cannot quite figure out what would be the value

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one other huge benefit: **memory efficiency**.  By having a streamed pipeline, client/server/client, all parties safely process data without running the risk of blowing up the memory allocation.  This is particularly useful on the server side, where you always have to assume the clients may do something malicious...

**Client Request Creation**

Suppose the ultimate source of your millions of users is a file.  You can create a stream source from this file:

```
val userFilePath : java.nio.file.Path = ???

val userFileSource = akka.stream.scaladsl.FileIO(userFilePath)
```

This source can you be use to create your http request which will stream the users to the service:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.{Chunked, ChunkStreamPart}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{RequestEntity, ContentTypes, HttpRequest}

val httpRequest : HttpRequest = 
  HttpRequest(uri = "http://filterService.io", 
              entity = Chunked.fromData(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, userFileSource))
```

**This request will now stream the users to the service without consuming the entire file into memory.**  Only chunks of data will be buffered at a time, therefore, you can send a request with potentially an infinite number of users and your client will be fine.

**Server Request Processing**

Similarly, your server can be designed to accept a request with an entity that can potentially be of infinite length.

Your questions says the service will filter the users, assuming we have a filtering function:

```
val isValidUser : (String) => Boolean = ???
```

This can be used to filter the incoming request entity and create a response entity which will feed the response:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Chunked

val route = extractDataBytes { userSource =>
  val responseSource : Source[ByteString, _] = 
    userSource
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .filter(isValidUser)
      .map(ByteString.apply)

  complete(HttpResponse(entity=Chunked.fromData(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, 
                                                responseSource)))
}
```

**Client Response Processing**

The client can similarly process the filtered users without reading them all into memory.  We can, for example, dispatch the request and send all of the valid users to the console:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http

Http()
  .singleRequest(httpRequest)
  .map { response =>
    response
      .entity
      .dataBytes
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .foreach(System.out.println)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. In our case, on the client, we  stream from a file, split the file into batches of 100, and then  mapAsyncUnordered using a function that calls singleRequest on that batch. I think this has the same effect as your example (I may be wrong)

Comment: On the server, I don't full understand what are the benefits of streaming. (a) clients could still overflow the API by making too many connection.  (b) we can still control the load on the server by configuring the number of connections and in-flight requests akka-http  allows

Comment: @EugeneMi Client: All of the batching and mapAsyncUnordered that you had to explicitly write I get for free by using `Chunked.fromData`.  Server: (a) A server is an akka-stream `Source` of `Connection` objects, so backpressure prevents DDoS attacks, (b) even when you limit the number of requests & connections then if your logic reads the entire entity into memory a single request can still blow up your memory by sending a HUGE entity.  Akka Http is backpressured all the way through: A server is a Source of Connections, a Connection is a Source of Requests, a Request is a Source of bytes.